# Julia - workspace()

Tags: julia, linux-mint, method-missing

I've been using Win7 to develop in Julia, and I've got a method called loadAll() which runs an include(x) on all relevant files (I'm simultaneously working on a bunch of scripts and I cant be bothered to write the full path for every specific file that I update

When I try running this method using a Linux mint computer it returns the error "ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant Model", where Model is a type which I've re-written on the win7 machine

I attempted to work around this by adding workspace() (crude, I know)  but it returned "ERROR: workspace not defined"

Additionally, if I exclude the script that loads the Model type (and all the other types) I get the error "ERROR: @doc not defined"

I would have posted this in the Julia forum but this seems like possibly something that might have to do with the OS rather than the Julia language itself, as I'm sure that if stuff like workspace() and @doc were malfunctioning it would already been solved

Has anybody had this experience that might understand what the problem is? Any help is greatly appreciated, as I would deeply prefer to be able to use Linux instead of windows

**EDIT:**

Further removing stuff, I removed all the @doc occurrences, and another error came along "ERROR: AbstractString not defined"

Comment: Are you using Julia v0.3 or lower version? My suggestion is to try Julia v0.4 or higher.

Comment: Thank you! Wow mine was v0.4, somehow I thought apt-get install julia would yield the freshest version

Comment: From memory, some repositories are still on v0.2! Best to use a binary from [julialang.org](http://julialang.org/) for the install.